# L'uso del "lei" sta diminuendo in tutta Italia?

Tags: word-usage, curiosity

Giusto per distrarmi dalla noia lavorativa post-ferragostana, vi faccio questa domanda.

Negli ultimi anni ho notato che, almeno qui a Milano, l'uso del *lei* sta diminuendo sensibilmente.

Qualche esempio:

- in ufficio diamo del *tu* anche ai dirigenti, cosa impensabile anche
  solo vent'anni fa;
- le commesse dei negozi, anche se non le hai mai viste prima in vita
  tua, si rivolgono a te come se fossi loro parente (è probabile che
  qui l'atteggiamento amichevole sia dettato più che altro dal
  tentativo di rifilarti qualcosa che non vuoi comprare).

In particolare, sicuramente per facilitare la comprensione, gli italiani danno del *tu* agli stranieri, anche quando userebbero il *lei* con un altro italiano.

Esempio: coda ad uno sportello pubblico, l'impiegato mi ha dato del *lei* mentre alla persona straniera in fila prima di me ha dato del *tu*.

È così in tutta Italia?

Comment: ***Umberto Eco: "Così il darci del Tu rischia di impoverire la nostra memoria e il nostro apprendimento"*** http://www.repubblica.it/cultura/2015/09/14/news/umberto_eco_cosi_il_darci_del_tu_rischia_di_impoverire_la_nostra_cultura_e_il_nostro_apprendimento_-122861035/

Comment: @Josh61 Non posso credere di aver notato una cosa già detta da UMBERTO ECO! La mia autostima è aumentata :)

Comment: Sono stata recentemente in Toscana e mi hanno dato sempre del lei. Ma sono rimasta molto stupita l'unica volta che ho dovuto prendere un tassì: a me (che sono straniera) l'autista ha dato sempre del lei, ma ha fermato per chiedere indicazioni stradali a un uomo anziano e gli si è rivolto dandogli del tu. Per esempio, alla fine gli ha detto: "Ti ringrazio!"

Comment: @Charo Credo che la scelta di dare del *tu* o del *lei* sia molto soggettiva. Ho visto spesso italiani dare del *tu* agli stranieri quando risulta chiaro che altrimenti non capirebbero. Comunque negli hotel, per quanto la mia esperienza non sia vasta, danno ancora del *lei* a tutti, quindi presumo anche i tassisti. Infine non è raro vedere giovani che danno del *tu* agli anziani, spesso facendoli pure contenti perché così si sentono giovani anche loro!

Comment: Avendo avuto a che fare con persone che si permettevano di dare del "tu" ad altri che non ritenevano al loro livello l'uso sempre piu' diffuso del "tu" a chi si sarebbe normalmente dato del "lei" mi da' sempre una cattiva impressione. Ho anche avuto chi si e' presentato a colloqui di lavoro dando del "tu"... A volte trovo difficile distinguere quando il "tu" e' risultato di un cambio della lingua, cattive abitudini o peggio... non sono al livello dei nonni che davano del "lei" ai propri genitori ma forse sto diventando vecchio...

Comment: @ErikvanDoren Non ci avevo pensato, ci sono anche quelli che danno del *tu* in senso dispregiativo! Addirittura ad un colloquio di lavoro, poi! Bel metodo per farsi scartare subito. Pensa che mio nonno ai suoi genitori dava del *voi*, mentre mia mamma chiede sempre che le venga dato del *tu*, altrimenti si sente vecchia! A me alcune volte dà fastidio quando persone che non conosco mi danno del *tu*, mi mettono un po' a disagio, probabilmente dipende anche da come sei di carattere, mia mamma è molto espansiva, mentre io sono più timida.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

L'uso del "tu" inceve che  del "lei" come pronome di cortesia sembra essere in aumento, come risulta anche dal seguente estratto da ***"[L'uso del lei"](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/uso-del-lei_(La-grammatica-italiana)/)***  da Treccanni.it:

> - ***Negli ultimi decenni il tu ha gradualmente ampliato la sua sfera d’uso, estendendosi a situazioni in cui prima non era previsto, come il rapporto tra insegnanti e studenti in certi settori della scuola.***  Anche gli usi non reciproci degli allocutivi sono negli ultimi decenni in forte diminuzione (ad esempio, è del 1975 una circolare che elimina nell’esercito l’uso del lei da inferiore a superiore e del tu da superiore a inferiore).
> - ***Di fronte a una diversa sensibilità dei parlanti, è consigliabile non abusare del tu in situazioni formali e mantenere il lei, specie con persone che non si conoscono.***

Answer (score 0):

Prima di tutto distinguerei gli ambienti non troppo formali dagli altri. Detto questo:
Non voglio dire cosa sia giusto in termini di regole, solo quello che vedo. La società moderna è molto diversa da quella di una volta.
Vorrei parlare di ambienti non troppo formali come bar, parrucchiere, locali.
Nella mia città, le forme di cortesia come signore/signora, in questi ambienti, vengono utilizzate per lo più per indicare una persona ritenuta "più vecchia".
Non implicano un rispetto particolare. Anzi.. capita moltissime volte, che i clienti ai quali viene dato del tu, vengono trattati meglio. Sicuramente con meno distanza... 
Per questo ed altri motivi, non tutti gradiscono l'uso eccessivo del lei, oppure degli appellativi signore/signora". In particolare se ripetuti ogni 3 parole. 
Senza generalizzare, penso che la causa sia il modo in cui spesso vengono usati, da chi tratta diversamente un cliente solo sulla base dell'età anagrafica, non sapendo niente di lui. 
Sono abituato alle usanze di altri paesi, nei quali gli adulti vengono trattati circa allo stesso modo. Vieni considerato adulto dai 20 anni in su e non dai 30/40. 
è più rilassante, i negozianti non contano le rughe. I clienti si trovano maggiormente a loro agio. Soprattutto se non sono proprio "anziani" in senso stretto.
In Italia vedo persone che hanno poco più di 30 anni, che trattano 40enni come se fossero i loro nonni..(per fare un esempio).
A volte essere trattati diversamente "solo" per motivi anagrafici, può fare andare via qualcuno. 
Vedo che oggi molti clienti scelgono il locale o bar, nel quale si trovano più a loro agio.

P.s: è solo il mio parere personale, basato su esperienze. Non generalizzo. Ogni persona ha esigenze diverse, le regole sono altre..

Dimenticavo: come si capisce che alcuni, usano le forme di cortesia solo per motivi anagrafici e non per rispetto?
Si offendono da morire se uno ricambia allo stesso modo. 
Questi, cercano un dialogo nel quale loro ti danno del "lei" perchè sei "vecchio", tu gli devi dare del "tu". Oppure loro ti chiamano "signore" ma tu devi chiamarli "ragazzo oppure signorina" anche se sono adulti anche loro. Questo lo trovo abbastanza grottesco, fra adulti. Non mi piace questa usanza. 
Non avendo i dati anagrafici, spesso, si basano solo sull'aspetto fisico. Una persona può avere un aspetto più giovanile ma essere nata prima rispetto ad un'altra.
Chi lo usa per puro rispetto, dovrebbe accettare un trattamento alla pari tipo:
"Lei" con "lei" tra adulti estranei.. oppure "signore" con "signora".
In altri paesi non viene inserita la data di nascita nel curriculum, per non mettere in posizioni di svantaggio chi è "più anziano".
A prescindere dagli errori.. oggi c'è una sensibilità diversa verso questi temi rispetto al passato. Ovviamente chi ha un curriculum con dei meriti apprezza alcune forme di cortesia maggiormente, sapendo che sono dedicate ai suoi successi, prestigio. Tutto un altro effetto ha l'uso insistente dell'appellativo signóre, utilizzato come semplice comparativo di "senex".

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE, @Paco! Quello che ci aspettiamo su questo sito come risposte a domande di questo genere non sono i pareri personali degli utenti, ma post basati su dati o su fonti attendibili.

Comment: Non mi risulta che l'utente che ha parlato della Toscana abbia fornito dati o fonti attendibili, verificabili. Ha raccontato cosa gli è successo. Comunque posso cancellarlo. Non è un problema. Volevo approfondire l'argomento analizzandolo da diversi punti di vista.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) for SE to distribute that content. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, consider taking a look at: [How does deleting work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/295232)?

Comment: Benvenuto @Paco! Considera che è sempre Charo che ha parlato della Toscana non in una risposta ma in un _commento_. Quest'ultimo strumento è generalmente più flessibile, contrariamente alle risposte, le quali tendono ad essere generalmente più solide e verificabili. Naturalmente non si vuol scoraggiare nessuno, anzi si vogliono incoraggiare risposte, purché non contengano solo o principalmente aneddoti.

Comment: @user5339 (già Paco): Hai 12 anni?

Comment: È tardi ormai, ma una risposta al massimo si cancella (pulsante "delete"), non si vandalizza.